# Sharepoint 2010 - External Webservices and Workflows

Tags: 2010, workflow, web-services

I've been searching the internet for a little bit for an answer to this question with all my answers have been pointing to "No" and "you can do it in sharepoint 2013"

Is there a way to have a Sharepoint 2010 Workflow kick off a an external webservice?  If so can you point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the best you could do I believe is to create your own workflow action that would introduce your own business logic that you could then call in your workflow.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13604.sharepoint-2010-create-a-workflow-activity-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  You gave me another avenue to look at.